# Saving data from MySQL table to a text file with Python

Tags: python, mysql

So I have a mysql table and I am trying to take each element from one of the fields of the table.  The field and table are both called "keywords".  In the field there are many different random words and I am trying to take all of those and save them to a text file.  Any help on how to implement this would be great, here is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", db="")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = """SELECT DISTINCT keywords FROM keywords"""
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchall()
db.close()

for s in sql:
   tweets = open("keywords.txt", "w")
```

What I was thinking is to turn what sql fetches into a list if possible and write that to the file.  But I am open to any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: why are you iterating over `for s in sql`, `sql` is a string...

Comment: Sorry i was just trying multiple different ways for this.  I didn't mean to copy and paste this version but basically the last line is what I am looking for to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", db="")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = """SELECT DISTINCT keywords FROM keywords"""
tweets = open("keywords.txt", "w")
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
   print>>tweets, row[0]
tweets.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: I think that cursor.execute(sql) is a long and you cannot iterate through it. Shouldn't it be something like for row in cursor: ... ?

Comment: @fanny: yes, that would work, but only if you add a line `cursor.execute(sql)` before loop. Which is not shorter, but may be cleaner.

Comment: you're right, cursor.execute(sql) must be called before :) And it works all right. My question concerns your code - in specific iterating through "for row in cursor.execute(sql)" - how come when I try to mimic your code I get a TypeError (as cursor.execute(sql) is a LONG) while you obviously do not? :)

Comment: I experience the save error as fanny. Instead, the following code is working.

`cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:`